# psql create user SUPER USER WITH password throwing syntax error message

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-13

I am trying to create a SUPERUSER PostgreSQL user with an encrypted password using psql.

```
CREATE USER my_username SUPERUSER WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'MYPASS';
```

However the above command results in the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"
LINE 1: CREATE USER my_username SUPERUSER WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'M...
```

But the following command works fine

```
CREATE USER my_username WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'MYPASS';
```

I am using PostgreSQL 13, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html

The correct form is:

```
CREATE USER my_username WITH SUPERUSER ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'MYPASS';
```